# Is there a way to write a custom postfix template for java declaring a new instance in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to be able to create the following snippet

```
Instance instance = new Instance();
```

using a custom postfix template.

I tried

```
$EXPR$ $expr$ = new $EXPR$();
```

But it transforms `Instance.instance` into `Instance = new Instance();` missing `instance`. Only the first letter of the instance identifier should be lowercase, e.g. `CustomTemplate` should be transformed into `CustomTemplate customTemplate = new CustomTemplate();`.

Is there a function like `lower($EXPR$)` to use? I found [Custom Postfix Templates](https://github.com/xylo/intellij-postfix-templates) plugin but I don't know if it helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it using Custom Postfix Templates:

```
.instance : new Instance
    CLASS     →  $expr$ $var:suggestVariableName()$ = new $expr$();
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is with Refactor > [Introduce Variable..](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/extract-variable.html)
Type: `new Instance` (or use Postfix `Instance.new`), and press (Windows: <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + V</kbd>, MacOS: <kbd>⌥ ⌘ V</kbd>).

There is also a related feature [request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186592).

Comment: After using **Refactor | Extract | Variable** on a class name in Intellij 2019.1.4, it says *Cannot perform refactoring. Unknown expression type.*. OK, it works with `new Instance` instead of `Instance`. Good answer.